# Python API Performance Issue for concurrent users

Tags: python, performance, flask, uwsgi, python-tesseract

I am new at developing a Python API and I am encountering some performance issue, when adding more concurrent users. I have a Flask API, with uWSGI and Nginx, everything Dockerized.

The API is doing some image processing transformations using OpenCV, has an object detection step using Tensorflow and some OCR steps using Tesseract as well. When deployed and tested on a user, the response is ok, when we start adding more concurrent users(even with decent numbers, like 50-100 concurrent users), the response times increase several times, up to 5-10 times more.

For uwsgi, I have set the following:

```
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
threads = 10
lazy-apps = true
```

Without these configs, I also had a problem of Bad Gateway responses.

Any suggestions about what I should try to update/change, in which area I should focus, are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What hardware are you running on? How high are the different metrics of your hardware (RAM, CPU, IO)? What response time do you get and what times do you expect?

Comment: I am testing on my MacOC HighSierra, deploying it later to an Oracle Enterprise Linux. I tested it through Docker with 8 CPUs and 10 GB or RAM. The CPU starts to grow to 80% and the memory increases significantly depending on the number of concurrent threads. As for the processing times, it jumps from 5 seconds to 50 seconds.